# gridview not recognizing protected property

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a web forms application written using asp.net 2.0/3.5.  I am upgrading this application to web forms 4.5.  I created a new project using vs 2012 and am creating new forms then copying/pasting code from the early version of the application. I have ran into conflicts, but have worked them out, except for the following.
I have a gridview which uses a protected property in code behind to determine whether it is being edited or not.
I am stumped why this is not working in 4.5.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Item Stock">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTotalQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalQty") %>' 
           Visible="<%# Not CBool(IsInEditMode) %>" />
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalQty" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalQty") %>' 
          Visible="<%# CBool(IsInEditMode) %>" />
          <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtendertq" FilterType="Custom, Numbers" ValidChars="." runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTotalQty">
         </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>    
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle CssClass="controltext" />
    <ItemStyle  Width="12%" />
 </asp:TemplateField>


Private isEditMode As Boolean = False
Protected Property IsInEditMode() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.isEditMode
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Me.isEditMode = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The reason I am transferring to 4.5 is because it is the first step on the way to convert vb.net to c# then to MVC.

Does anyone have any idea why this is no longer working?

Thanks so much

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you get any exception?

Comment: Please remove CBool as IsInEditMode is already a Boolean.

Comment: I removed CBool, but it still isn't recognized.  I thought my code looked good to.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the exception.